# SDL2 image load in windows 10

Tags: c++, sdl-2

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Titlu",
        100,
        100,
        600,
        400,
        SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
        );
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    int p = 0;
    SDL_Event* mainEvent = new SDL_Event();
    SDL_Texture* grass_image = nullptr;

    grass_image = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer,"grass.bmp");
    if (grass_image == NULL)
        std::cout << "FAILED";
    SDL_Rect grass_rect;
    grass_rect.x = 10;
    grass_rect.y = 50;
    grass_rect.w = 250;
        grass_rect.h = 250;
    while (!p && mainEvent->type != SDL_QUIT)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,grass_image,NULL,&grass_rect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    delete mainEvent;


    return 0;

}
```

grass_image = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer,"grass.bmp"); does not work and returns NULL the path of the image is good.

Please tell me if i did something wrong or if can give me a fix for incompatibility with my windows 10 or my visual studio 2015 update 3 
note that my window is white instead of black when i run it .

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: You could use `SDL_LoadBMP` for bmp formats. Where is your `IMG_Init` with formats you want it to load? Check your working directory with e.g. [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx). Look what error it gives you (`IMG_GetError`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `renderer` is NULL. Initialize it like this:

```
SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```